# Any way to use variables as rules and prerequisites in GNU Make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to set up my Makefile in such a way that I can define all of the inputs and outputs in some variables so I only have to write a single rule to compile the project. This allows me to minimize Makefile code and still have control over what is in my project. This is the relevant snippet of code:

```
ROOT_OBJS= \
    $(B)/main.o \
    $(B)/src1.o

ROOT_SRC= \
    $(SRC)/main.cpp \
    $(SRC)/src1.cpp


$(TARGET) : $(ROOT_OBJS)
    $(LD) $(LD_FLAGS) $^ -o $@


$(ROOT_OBJS) : $(ROOT_SRC)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

This mostly works except for the `$<` part in the second rule, it always uses main.cpp. Is there any fix to this or am I going about this the wrong way?

EDIT: for clarification, this is the output I expect:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
g++ src1.cpp -o src1.o
```

This is the output I get:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main.o
g++ main.cpp -o src1.o
```

I am aware this is because `$<` takes the first dependency, I thought make would be smart enough to figure it out because the .o behavior is what I want.

`$^` is not what I am looking for. I want gcc to make a separate object file for each cpp file.

Comment: You don't need the second rule at all. `make` knows how to create `.o` from `.cpp`.

Comment: "it always uses main.cpp" does not seem wrong. You probably imply that it never processes src1. How so? What output/behaviour/symptom makes you think so? Please demonstrate the problem you have. What did you do? E.g. which file did you touch? What do you expect?

Comment: Are you looking for `$^` which inserts the entire dependency line?

Comment: @Yunnosch I edited the OP for clarification.

Comment: @ryan have a look at my approach of doing that https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$<` always takes the *first* prerequisite. Since your rule expands to

```
$(B)/main.o $(B)/src1.o : $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/src1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

`$(SRC)/main.cpp` is always that first prerequisite. **There is no magical connection between `$(B)/main.o` and `$(SRC)/main.cpp` as far as `make` is concerned**.

If you want your rules to make this connection, you have to code it into the rules. There are several ways to get this right. The most straight forward is to write separate rules for each target:

```
$(B)/main.o : $(SRC)/main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
$(B)/src1.o : $(SRC)/src1.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You can also use a pattern rule like this:

```
$(B)/%.o : $(SRC)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Here, `$<` does the right thing because `$(SRC)/%.cpp` is parameterized with the pattern, so it will expand to the correct source file.

The biggest gun you have is *generating* the individual rules:

```
STEMS := main src1

$(foreach stem,$(STEMS), \
    $(eval $(B)/$(stem).o: $(SRC)/$(stem).cpp ; $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@))
```

Here I loop over all the words in `$(STEMS)` with the `$(foreach)` intrinsic function call and generate one rule per iteration with the `$(eval)` function call. **This is GNU Make syntax, only**, other `make` implementations are likely not to have these features. However, it is the most general and flexible way to tell `make` what to do. GNU Make's function call syntax is turing complete, so you can perform any calculations you need to come up with the correct rules. Readability will suffer, though, so use this with care.

Comment: Is there any way I can use a pattern rule on the variables? Just curious.

Comment: There's also the possibility of using static pattern rule: It's basically a pattern rule that's restricted to a given set of files: `$(files) : $(pattern) : $(prerequisites) ; $(recipe)`. See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern for details. As far as I remember, those rules have some quirks that make them hard to use right, but that does not mean they are not useful for your case.

Comment: `As far as I remember, those rules have some quirks` Not too much. Basically, they are _called_ "pattern rules", but _treated_ as "explicit rules". So they can be viewed as a sort of shorthand of "foreach".